# MYSQL Retrieving data from a table where id is not present in a column of two differents tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

What is the right syntax for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM gals 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_gal FROM paginas_principales)
     AND id NOT IN (SELECT id_gal FROM paginas_secundarias)
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: The question mark at the end probably is part of your question and not of the code block? In addition to the answer below, the ending double quote should also be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, the question mark is not part of the code block. Sorry for that mistake. This is my first time answering here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be:

```
SELECT * FROM gals 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_gal FROM paginas_principales)
     AND id NOT IN (SELECT id_gal FROM paginas_secundarias) ORDER BY id DESC
         ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM gal LEFT JOIN primary ON gal.id_gal = primary.id_gal LEFT JOIN secondary ON gal.id_gal = secondary.id_gal WHERE primary.id_gal IS NULL AND secondary.id_gal IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM gals g,(SELECT id_gal FROM paginas_principales)t 
WHERE g.id !=t.id_gal 
     AND g.$whateveryourcolumn !=t.id_gal ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: You seem to be missing one of the tables mentioned in the question.